# routing event to other user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, event-handling

I need some assistance here.

I have got a button on my window. when button is clicked I want to route the action taken to the event already created in other usercontrol. These usercontrol is embedded in the window itself.

the event in usercontrol is

```
public void Item_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
               object selected = this.GetType().GetField("Person", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(this);
               this. PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = selected;

        }
```

button as created in window is as :

```
<Button Content="clickme" Name="click" Grid.Column="2" Height="20" Width="50" Click="click_Click" />
```

button event in the window is as shown below:

```
 private void click_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

        {
         /// dosomething   
        }
```

can someone help me here please?? I want to call Item_checked event on Button click.

Comment: Where is Item_Checked coming from?

Comment: Let's say it's a custom event in another user control .

Comment: To sum up in the end you wish to call another method when Button clicked. Well then do so. Its just a simple method call. Method Item_Checked is just a normal method that can be called as it is or can be added to a delegate and called form delegate when delegate invoked. In the end its a method like every other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem in programming. The generally accepted solution is simply to add a new method containing what is currently in your `Item_Checked` event handler and then to call that method from the handler and anywhere else you may want to:

In `UserControl`:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    object selected = this.GetType().GetField("Person", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(this);
    this.PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = selected;
}

public void Item_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

In `Window` (where `yourUserControl` is a reference to your `UserControl`):

```
private void click_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    yourUserControl.DoSomething();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call with null value as RoutedEventArgs as follows

```
Item_Checked(PropertyGrid1,null);
```

Comment: Instead of null you can take EventArgs.Empty.